# version of Windows Installer ISO

Tags: windows, version, iso

i have simple question. It Is Possible find out a windows version (eq XP, Vista, 7) install from ISO. or extracted ISO. example. I have a CD install with windows. And my task is find out what windows is it? I have full access to CD but I can not run installation to see version.

THX

Answer (score 4):

You can check out the ei.cfg file inside the sources folder. This will tell you what version of WIN7 it is (ultimate / professional etc.). Also check out this link:

http://www.waynezim.com/2012/10/how-to-determine-the-version-of-your-windows-iso-file/

This will let you know a little more information like the build. Just as a tip, if you actually delete the ei.cfg file before burning to a DVD, when trying to install WIN7 it will bring up an option of what version you want to install.